# how can i solve this problem in react native in expo freamwork something with expo schema

Tags: react-native, expo

Enter image description [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Azuig.jpg)

> Warning: Problem validating app.json: Unable to perform cache refresh for C:\Users\PC-2020\AppData\Local\Expo\schema-37.0.0.json: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 104.197.216.164:443

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
"sdkVersion": "3X.0.0"
```

to your app.json